# How to integrate PushWoosh in iOS application for VOIP background

Tags: ios, background, voip, pushwoosh

I have integrated PushWoosh in my ios app as per given [guide](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-ios-sdk). But still I am not able to get simple or VOIP notification.

Is there any additional settings should I add?

Which device token we need to add for testing device?

Right now I have added device token which I got inside `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

Comment: Can you please mention your iOS version here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have following thing properly, then you have definitely got the notification.

1 ) Add your `Pushwoosh_APPID` into your `.plist` file

2 ) Implement below method as follow, So you can receive alert when receive notification.

```
 - (void) onPushAccepted:(PushNotificationManager *)pushManager withNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushNotification
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Push Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"onPushAccepted : %@", pushNotification] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
      UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
      [alertController addAction:alertAction];
      [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
   });
}
```

**Note:-**

If you have working with iOS 10 or above, Then it is compulsory to ON remote notification in capabilities.

Go to -> Project setting -> capabilities -> `Enable` Push Notifications.

Go to -> Project setting -> capabilities -> Background Mode -> `Enable` Remote Notification and VoIp

Comment: I tried to use above code with application appDelegate file but still notification does not received by the app. I am generating notification from pushWoosh website portal. All the settings inside Capabilities are also corrected. I am getting notification with default app available on pushwoosh but If I use custom app then not able to get notification.

Comment: Have you check your provisional profile and p.12 certificate ios Correct .

Comment: Yes. I am using auto configuration

Comment: Tried with manual config but still not receiving notification